# How best to clean up Mercurial repository with many old open branches?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have inherited a code base stored in a mercurial repository.

The repo has about thirty open branches, including:

- old release branches for releases that have long been superseded.
- old feature branches that have been merged into trunk(*) but not closed.
- old feature branches that have been abandoned (not merged anywhere).

Many of these old branches have not been used for years.

I would like to close these old branches so that `hg branches` will give me an accurate picture of current ongoing work.

If I close so many old branches, I imagine that's going to mess up my graph in TortoiseHg and make it harder to follow what's been going on in the past.

That's not a massive problem, but it has me wondering **is there a better way to clean up a mercurial repo with many old and inactive branches**?

(*) default was abandoned and replaced with a primary branch named 'trunk'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Closing branch in Mercurial just hide head of this branch from `hg heads` output, nothing more: merged branch with not have head anyway
2. If you perform partial clone, you'll get in clone only needed|used parts of source repo: `hg clone -r tip ...` will clone only ancestors of current tip, all unmerged branches will be ignored (deleting merged branches is, anyway, bad idea)